# ABP Framework Azure Devops Build Not Finding ABP Libraries

Tags: abp

I have setup a build pipeline for My ABP Project. I have install ABP SDK and Visual studio build tools in the build server. But It shows an error that it cannot find any ABP Volo Packages for e.g **Unable to find package Volo.Abp.LanguageManagement.EntityFrameworkCore** is one of the error .. it actually cannot find any of the packages. I have the config in root too
[image]

Comment: Make sure your `NuGet.Config` file is placed root folder of the project. Does it exist?

Comment: Yes sir I will update my question to include the screenshot too. @enisn

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution after a long research
Add task Use .NET Core task to your pipeline and select the version that’s throwing you error E.g screenshot below
[image]